# How may I make this formula more concise, in terms of computation and notation

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

I want to express the following in a computationally less-loaded way:

$\forall i < A [F(i) = B \implies H(i) = C]$

Taking some shortcuts, this says:

> For all $i$, if $F(i) = B$, then $H(i)$ should equal $C$.

Considering the following fact, this is making us check too much: $\forall i, j < A [F(i) = F(j) \implies H(i) = H(j)]$. Hence, a computationally more concise way to say the same is:

> For the first $i$ satisfying $F(i) = B$, $H(i)$ should equal $C$.

However, the best I can think of for this is very heavy in notation:

$\left|\{i<A:F(i)=B\}\right| >0 \implies H(\min{\{i<A:F(i)=B\}})=C$

Is there a best-of-both-worlds solution to this?

Comment: Does $i$ range over a finite or infinite set?

Comment: @R.Burton Finite set. Precisely, $i$ is from $\mathbb{N}_0$. It is finite for being limited by $A$ from above.

Answer (score 1):

The formula $\forall i<A.F(i)=B\implies H(i)=C$ states that for *every* instance of $i<A$, if $F(i)=B$ then $H(i)=C$. It is *not* sufficient to check only the least $i$ such that $F(i)=B$.

Unless $F$ is stated to be a bijection, it may be the case that for the least $i<A$ such that $F(i)=B$, $H(i)=C$, and yet for some $i<j<A$, $F(j)=B$ and $H(j)\ne C$.

For example, say that $A=3$, $B=1$ and $C=4$. If $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$, and $F(2)=1$, and $H(0)=0$, $H(1)=4$, and $H(2)=1$, then your formula...

$$\left\vert\{i<A\mid F(i)=B\}\right\vert>0\implies H\left(\min\{i<A\mid F(i)=B\}\right)=C$$

...holds, since both the consequent and antecedent are true (1 is th minimum, and $F(1)=1$ and $H(1)=4$). However, the orignal formula...

$$\forall i<A.F(i)=B\implies H(i)=C$$

...does not, since $F(2)=1$ and $H(2)=1\ne4$.

As far as notation goes, the original formula is about as concise as it can possibly be.

---

As for making the *evaluation* of the original formula more computation friendly, this is what I would do:

Let $G(i)=\begin{cases}1&F(i)=B\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $K(i)=\begin{cases}1&F(i)=B\land H(i)=C\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then...

$$\forall i<A.F(i)=B\implies H(i)=C\iff i<A\implies G(i)-K(i)=0$$

This works best if you treat $G$ and $K$ as 'vectors' - then $G-K$ is the zero vector. In the above example where $B=1$ and $C=4$, you get $G=(0,1,1)$ and $K=(0,1,0)$.

$$(0,1,1)-(0,1,0)=(0,0,1)\ne(0,0,0),\qquad\therefore \neg(\forall i<A.F(i)=B\implies H(i)=C)$$

By this method, the formula reduces to...

$$\forall i<A.F(i)=B\implies H(i)=C\iff G-K=\mathbf{0}$$

I can't guarantee that there isn't a more computationally efficinet method of checking your formula (there almost certainly is), but this works well enough. If your doing this by hand, you can simplify the process to:

1) write out $F$ in one row

2) write $H$ in a row below it

3) every time you see $B$ in the top row, draw a box around it and the entry below it.

4) continue until you hit a box whose lower entry is not $C$ or you reach the end of the list.

**Edit:**

OP has clarified that the function $F$ satisfies $\forall i,j<A.F(i)=F(j)\implies H(i)=H(j)$

That being the case, we need only check that if there is *at least* one $i$ such that $F(i)=B$, then $H(i)=C$. As a first order formula, this is written...

$$\exists i<A.F(i)=B\implies\exists i<A.F(i)=B\land H(i)=C$$

As for an algorithm to evaluate the formula, I'm not sure whether it is more or less efficient to parse $F$ and $H$ through to the first $i$ satisfying the formula, or to treat them as vectors, as above. It may depend on the value of $A$. In either case, the original method can be modified to work with the new formula.

Let $G(i)=\begin{cases}1&F(i)=B\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $K(i)=\begin{cases}1&F(i)=B\land H(i)=C\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then...

$$\exists i<A.F(i)=B\land H(i)=C\iff G=\mathbf{0}\lor K(i)\ne\mathbf{0}$$

By hand...

1) write out $F$ in one row

2) write $H$ in a row below it

3) find the first instance of $B$ in the top row - your formula holds iff the entry below it is $C$ or there are no $B$

Comment: I see that a lot of effort has been put here, but unfortunately, I have to say that there must have been a misunderstanding. The statement $\forall i < A [F(i) = B \implies H(i) = C]$ **combined with** the fact $\forall i, j < A [F(i) = F(j) \implies H(i) = H(j)]$ is to be simplified. Maybe I should have used something stronger than "Considering the fact"; I thought it'd fit the bill. Your example is not compliant with the fact I'm asserting, since $F(1) = F(2)$ but $H(1) \ne H(2)$. Hence, it is not a contradictory counterexample. I am sorry.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin It's alright. I've edited the answer, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your continual effort to help. If I am understanding this correctly, your solution requires at least one $i$ to exist satisfying $F(i) = B \wedge H(i) = C$ to be true. There are further cases in which the original formula is true, namely, $\forall i < A. F(i) \ne B$ (adopting your notation). This is why I used an implication on the latest formula in my question, and not just the consequent of it. This does suggest that I could change update that last formula in my question as $\exists i<A. F(i)=B \implies \exists i<A. F(i) = B \wedge H(i) = C$, which is at least easier to read.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin You're right. I didn't think about the case where $\forall i<A. F(i)\ne B$. Now that you mention, your second formula guarantees that either there is at least one $i$ such that $F(i)=B\land H(i)=C$, or $\forall i<A.F(i)\ne B$.